# Calculating the bounding box of a random triangle using coordinates

Tags: haskell, geometry, bounding-box

I am looking for an appropriate way to calculate the rectangular bounding box of a triangle shape which has three corners given as points - (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3).

Here is the data type that I am using (as suggested, I added more constructors):

```
data Shape =
     Circle Point Double |
     Rectangle Point Point |
     Triangle Point Point Point
```

The bounding box function should be of the form "bounding :: Shape -> Shape".
I have also tried the bounding boxes of a rectangle and a circle:

```
bounding :: Shape -> Shape
bounding (Rectangle (Point x y) (Point z z1)) = (Rectangle (Point x y) (Point z z1))
bounding (Circle (Point p w) r) = (Rectangle (Point (p-r) (w-r)) (Point (p+r) (w+r)))
```

Are these right provided that the graphics coordinate system should be used (where (x,y) coordinates should be treated as (x,-y) instead)?

Could someone give me a helping hand please? 
P.S. No graphics library is required.

Comment: Surely your output type should be some kind of bounding box instead of another triangle?

Comment: @dave4420 Yes, the output should only be an encompassing rectangle.

Comment: But your type for `Shape` only lists triangles as possible shapes. Are you omitting something?

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? Have you got any code?

You need:

```
 data Shape = Triangle Point Point Point | Rectangle Point Point
```

Assuming x increases to the right and y increases to the up. Upper left corner will be (min{x1, x2, x3}, max{y1, y2, y3}) and you need right lower corner.

---

#### Edit

x should increase to the right and y to the down. I added triangle one, deleted unnecessary parentheses and derived (Show) to be able to print Shape data type. Whole code for you:

```
data Point = Point Double Double deriving (Show)

data Shape =
        Circle Point Double |
        Rectangle Point Point |
        Triangle Point Point Point deriving (Show)

bounding :: Shape -> Shape
bounding (Rectangle (Point x y) (Point z z1)) = Rectangle (Point x y) (Point z z1)
bounding (Circle (Point p w) r) = Rectangle (Point (p-r) (w-r)) (Point (p+r) (w+r))
bounding (Triangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) (Point x3 y3)) = Rectangle 
        (Point (minimum [x1, x2, x3]) (minimum [y1, y2, y3])) 
        (Point (maximum [x1, x2, x3]) (maximum [y1, y2, y3]))
```

Comment: Tyvm for your answer. Actually, y should increase to the down... (graphics coordinates requirement)

Comment: Best regards, kyticka! I am really grateful for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Based upon @dave4420's excellent observation, I am assuming that `Rectangles` are aligned with the x/y axes.

Based upon your rule for `Circle`, it appears the point with the smallest x,y comes first, and the point with the largest x,y comes second in the `Rectangle`.

You should probably stick to `x` and `y` with numeric suffixes instead of inventing new names like `p`, `w`, `z` and `z1` which are very confusing.

The bounding box of a `Rectangle` is the `Rectangle` itself.

The bounding box of a `Triangle` is going to be a `Rectangle` with the smallest and largest x,y from any point.

```
bounding :: Shape -> Shape
bounding rect@(Rectangle _ _) = rect
bounding (Circle (Point x y) r) = Rectangle p1 p2 where
  p1 = (Point (x-r) (y-r))
  p2 = (Point (x+r) (y+r))
bounding (Triangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) (Point x3 y3)) = Rectangle p1 p2 where
  p1 = Point (minimum [x1 x2 x3]) (minimum [y1 y2 y3])
  p2 = Point (maximum [x1 x2 x3]) (maximum [y1 y2 y3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm only posting this answer to make the point that bounding boxes and rectangles are not the same things.

```
data Point = Point Double Double   -- Point x y

data BoundingBox = BoundingBox Double Double Double Double
                            -- top    left   bottom right

data Shape
    = Circle Point Double
    | Rectangle Point Point Double
        -- yes, you need two points and a scalar to specify arbitrary rectangles
    | Triangle Point Point Point

boundingBox :: Shape -> BoundingBox
boundingBox (Circle (Point x y) r) = BoundingBox (y-r) (x-r) (y+r) (x+r)
boundingBox (Rectangle (Point x0 y0) (Point x1 y1) d)
        = BoundingBox (minimum ys) (minimum xs) (maximum ys) (maximum xs) where
    xs = [x0, x1, x1+dx, x0+dx]
    ys = [y0, y1, y1+dy, y0+dy]
    d' = d / ((x0-x1)^^2 + ((y0-y1)^^2)
    dx = d' * (y0-y1)
    dy = d' * (x1-x0)
boundingBox (Triangle (Point x0 y0) (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2))
        = BoundingBox (minimum ys) (minimum xs) (maximum ys) (maximum xs) where
    xs = [x0, x1, x2]
    ys = [y0, y1, y2]
```

As an exercise, factor out the common code from the `Rectangle` and `Triangle` cases. (Bonus points for finding and fixing any bugs I've placed in the `Rectangle` case.)

Comment: I presume that your `Rectangle` is not required to be aliged with the axes.  However, with three points, you can specify things that don't have a 90-degree corner.  You only need two points and a scalar.  The points specify the length and angle of one side, and the scalar specifies the length of the other perpendicular side.